# Select Periods but Not Number Elements with Decimal Points

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use `regex` in `C#` on filenames, to select the periods `.` and replace them with spaces .

https://regex101.com/r/HfZPLo/3

However I want to preserve certain elements with numbers that may contain decimal points:

```
2CH
5.1CH 
DTS5.1
DD7.1

123k
123.5k
1300.5K

60fps
23.976fps
29.97fps

48kHz
22.05kHz
44.1kHz
```

---

**Filename Examples**

```
File.x264.CRF32.23.976fps.AAC.DTS5.1.123.5k.44.1kHz

File.x264.CRF32.29.97fps.AAC.DD7.1.123.5k.22.05kHz

File.x264.CRF32.23.976fps.AAC.5.1CH.123.5k.44.1kHz

File.x264.CRF32.23.976fps.AAC.5.1.Dolby.123.5k.44.1kHz
```

---

**Regex Rules**

```
(?<!\.DTS|\.\d\d\d\d\d\d|\.\d\d\d\d\d|\.\d\d\d\d|\.\d\d\d|\.\d\d|\.\d)(\.)(?!CH\.|\d\.|fps\.|kHz\.|k\.|m\.)
```

I cannot seem to get all the Negative Lookahead and Lookbehinds to catch all of the elements. Sometimes one overwrites the other, such as if `DTS5.1` and `123.5k` are next to each other.

Also it needs to work if these filename tags are in any order.

---

**Desired Result**

```
File x264 CRF32 23.976fps AAC DTS5.1 123.5k 44.1kHz

File x264 CRF32 29.97fps AAC DD7.1 123.5k 22.05kHz

File x264 CRF32 23.976fps AAC 5.1CH 123.5k 44.1kHz

File x264 CRF32 23.976fps AAC 5.1 Dolby 123.5k 44.1kHz
```

Comment: And of those examples, what would your desired result look like?

Comment: @JvdV I have updated my question with desired result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will take a look at this.

Comment: I think `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!CRF\d*)(\d\.\d)|\.", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : " ")` works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One issue, between `CRF32` and `29.97fps` https://rextester.com/EBD61312

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I see you updated it.

Comment: So, is it working?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have been testing your first one, it is working. I will take a look at the new one you posted.

Comment: No, wait, I modified it to `var m_pat = @"\bCRF\d+|[A-Za-z]+(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-zA-Z]*"` and then `string.Join(" ", Regex.Matches(s, m_pat).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value))`. I will post the first one then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What does this modified version improve?

Comment: @MattMcManis It does not improve, it is just following a bit different logic. It is more restrictive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!CRF\d*)(\d\.\d)|\.", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : " ")
```

The `(?<!CRF\d*)(\d\.\d)|\.` regex will match and capture into Group 1 any `digit.digit` that is not preceded with `CRF` and any amount of digits, or will just match a dot in any other context, and `Regex.Replace` will replace the match with the contents of Group 1 if Group 1 matched, else, will replace the match with a space.

So, the code above actually means *replace any dot with space if the dot is not in between two digits, unless the initial digits are preceded with `CRF`*.

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/iYrx53):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "File.x264.CRF32.23.976fps.AAC.DTS5.1.123.5k.44.1kHz","File.x264.CRF32.29.97fps.AAC.DD7.1.123.5k.22.05kHz","File.x264.CRF32.23.976fps.AAC.5.1CH.123.5k.44.1kHz","File.x264.CRF32.23.976fps.AAC.5.1.Dolby.123.5k.44.1kHz"};
//var m_pat = @"\bCRF\d+|[A-Za-z]+(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-zA-Z]*";
foreach (var s in strs) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!CRF\d*)(\d\.\d)|\.", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : " "));
    //Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Regex.Matches(s, m_pat).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value)) );
}
```

Output:

```
File x264 CRF32 23.976fps AAC DTS5.1 123.5k 44.1kHz
File x264 CRF32 29.97fps AAC DD7.1 123.5k 22.05kHz
File x264 CRF32 23.976fps AAC 5.1CH 123.5k 44.1kHz
File x264 CRF32 23.976fps AAC 5.1 Dolby 123.5k 44.1kHz
```

Note I added another, *matching and extracting then joining* solution, but it seems longer. The pattern there means to match

- `\bCRF\d+` - whole word `CRF` abd 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `[A-Za-z]+(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` - 1+ letters and an optional int/float number
- `|` - or
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-zA-Z]*` - a float/int number and then 0+ letters.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it for a while more on different filenames and accept your answer.